# schedule localnotifcation on future date range

Tags: ios, localnotification

```
- (void) scheduleGeneralNotificationFrequentlyWithItem:(ToDoItem *)item interval:(int)minutesBefore frequent:(NSCalendarUnit)frequentUnit{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:item.day];
    [dateComps setMonth:item.month];
    [dateComps setYear:item.year];
    [dateComps setHour:item.hour];
    [dateComps setMinute:item.minute];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    [dateComps release];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = [itemDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(minutesBefore*60)];
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    if (!item.eventName) {
        item.eventName = @"My event name";
    }
    localNotif.alertBody = item.alertBody;
    localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Details", nil);

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;


    localNotif.userInfo = item.data; // some data
    localNotif.repeatInterval = frequentUnit; // here I put NSDayCalendarUnit
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
    NSString *isDisableLocalPush = [Settings getSetting:kPraktijDisableLocalPushKey];
    if ([isDisableLocalPush isEqualToString:kJSONValueYes]) { //disable all notifications after added it
        [self disableAllLocationPushNotifications];
    }
}
```

here in above code, it will schedule daily till localNotif.fireDate , right?

what I am trying to achieve is : 
schedule notification for each day on next one month to another month
eg: daily notification for 2013/march/01 to 2013/may/01

Answer (score 0):

No, it will schedule daily notification starting from the fire date (until you cancel it).

if you want to schedule for a date range and it does not exceed the limit of local notification you can set at one time (which is 64, still less than 2 months you required), I think the best would be to schedule the local notification one by one for every day.

Just start with the NSDate object for the starting fire date, schedule the local notification without repeat interval, increase the NSDate by a day, and repeat scheduling the local notification until it reaches the end date of your range.